# Showing AdMob in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a DrawerLayout and I want to add an AdMob Fragment. I want to add AdMob at position bottom of Fragments but I don't know how I do it.

How can I do it ?

I'm trying this.

**DrawerLayout.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dl">

   <FrameLayout 
       android:id="@+id/fl"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"       
       >

       <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
           android:id="@+id/adView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           ads:adSize="BANNER"
           ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
           android:gravity="bottom"
           >
       </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

   </FrameLayout>

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/lv"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#e9ba68"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#ac453c"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
       >
   </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**DrawerLayout Fragment**

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    private ActionBar ab;
    private DrawerLayout dl;
    private ListView lv;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle tg;

    private List<ItensListView> fragments;
    private CharSequence tl; //titulo principal
    private CharSequence tlf; //titulo fragment 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_drawerlayout);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar)));
        init();

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            selectedItem(0);
        }       
    }

    private void init(){
        //actionbar
        onConfigActionBar();
        //listview
        configItensListView();
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);               
        lv.setAdapter(new DrawerLayoutListViewAdapter(this, fragments));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);        
        //drawerlayout
        dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.dl);
        //actionbardrawertoggle
        tg = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.drawable.btmenu, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tl);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tlf);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        dl.setDrawerListener(tg);
        tl = tlf = getTitle();
    }

    /** ativa actionbar e botao home na action bar */
    private void onConfigActionBar(){
        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }




    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        tg.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tg.syncState();
    }

    /** necessario */
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         FragmentTransaction ft;
         Fragment frag;
         if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_chat){
             frag = new HelloBubblesActivity();
             ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
             ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag,"HelloBubblesActivity");
             //ft.addToBackStack("back");
             ft.commit();
         }
         if (tg.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }


     /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_drawer_layout, menu);

        return true;
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean status = dl.isDrawerOpen(lv);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!status);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        selectedItem(position);     
    }

    /** seleciona o fragment q sera usado */
    private void selectedItem(int position){
        FragmentTransaction ft;
        Fragment frag;
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                //frag = new InicioFrag();
                frag = new InicioFrag();
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag, "InicioFrag");
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                frag = new ApresentacaoFrag();
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                frag = new ComoJogarFrag();
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                //ft.addToBackStack("back");
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                frag = new PerfilFrag();
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                //ft.addToBackStack("back");
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 4:
                frag = new UsuariosRanking();
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                //ft.addToBackStack("back");
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 5:
                frag = new ContatoFrag();
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                //ft.addToBackStack("back");
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 6:
                clearPrefences();
            default:
                System.exit(0);
                break;

        }

        lv.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setCustomTitle(fragments.get(position).getTexto());
        dl.closeDrawer(lv);
    }

    /** define o titulo da actionbar */
    private void setCustomTitle(String title){
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(title);
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, BatalhaConfigs.FONT), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ab.setTitle(s);
        tl = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        BatalhaSemOponenteFrag bsof = (BatalhaSemOponenteFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("BatalhaSemOponenteFrag");
        BatalhaComOponenteFrag bcof = (BatalhaComOponenteFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("BatalhaComOponenteFrag");
        InicioFrag ini = (InicioFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("InicioFrag");
        HelloBubblesActivity chat = (HelloBubblesActivity)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("HelloBubblesActivity");

        if(bsof != null && bsof.isVisible()){
            return;
        }else if(bcof != null && bcof.isVisible()) {
            return;
        }else if(chat != null && chat.isVisible()){
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putSerializable("infoBatalha", BatalhaConfigs.INFO_BATALHA);
            params.putSerializable("listBadgesUsuarioGanhou", (Serializable)BatalhaConfigs.LIST_BADGESGANHA);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment frag = new JogarComOponenteFrag();
            frag.setArguments(params);
            ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
            ft.commit();
        }else if(ini != null && !ini.isVisible()){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment frag = new InicioFrag();
            ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
            ft.commit();
        }else if(ini != null && ini.isVisible()){
            //System.exit(0);
            closeApp();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        //Log.i("RESUME: ", "FEZ RESUME");
        super.onResumeFragments();
    }

    /** Configura o List com as informacoes **/
    private void configItensListView(){
        fragments = new ArrayList<ItensListView>();
        //define
        ItensListView itens1 = new ItensListView("Iniciar o Jogo", R.drawable.menu_jogo);
        ItensListView itens2 = new ItensListView("Apresentação do Jogo", R.drawable.menu_apresentacao);
        ItensListView itens3 = new ItensListView("Como Jogar", R.drawable.menu_como_jogar);
        ItensListView itens4 = new ItensListView("Perfil", R.drawable.menu_perfil);
        ItensListView itens5 = new ItensListView("Ranking", R.drawable.menu_ranking);
        ItensListView itens6 = new ItensListView("Contato", R.drawable.menu_contato);
        ItensListView itens7 = new ItensListView("Trocar Usuário", R.drawable.exit_session);
        ItensListView itens8 = new ItensListView("Sair", R.drawable.logout);
        //add
        fragments.add(itens1);
        fragments.add(itens2);
        fragments.add(itens3);
        fragments.add(itens4);
        fragments.add(itens5);
        fragments.add(itens6);
        fragments.add(itens7);
        fragments.add(itens8);
    }

    private void closeApp(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomDrawerLayout.this);
        alert.setTitle("Batalha Jurídica");
        alert.setMessage("Deseja realmente sair ?");
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setNegativeButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        alert.setPositiveButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.show();

    }



    /** remove todas as preferencias da session */
    private void clearPrefences(){
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginView.class));
    }



    /** AdMob */
    public static class AdMobFrag extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
            AdView mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dl">

   <LinearLayout              
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >
     <FrameLayout 
         android:id="@+id/fl"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:wieght="1"/>

       <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
           android:id="@+id/adView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           ads:adSize="BANNER"
           ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
           android:gravity="bottom"
           >
       </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
   </LinearLayout>

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/lv"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#e9ba68"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#ac453c"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
       >
   </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Put this code in your Activity onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
  super.onCreate(b);
  ...
  ...

  AdView mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: but how could I open the AdMob ?

Comment: What does it mean "open the Admob"?

Comment: I thought you understand that you have to move adMob request code in your activity. I've added it to my answer.